# Creating an expression tree for prefix expression

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I would like to create an expression tree for a given expression string in prefix notation (e.g. a call would be create_expression_tree("+ * 2 6 / 3") . Sample output:

[image: Sample output]

This is what I have worked on so far:

```py
def create_expression_tree(prefix_exp_str, start_pos):
    print(start_pos)
    start_pos += 1
    op = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    element = prefix_exp_str[start_pos]
    if element == " ":
        element = prefix_exp_str[start_pos + 1]
        start_pos += 1
    if element not in op:
        return (LinkedBinaryTree.Node(int(element)), start_pos)
    else:
        left = create_expression_tree(prefix_exp_str, start_pos)
        right = create_expression_tree(prefix_exp_str, left[1])
        return LinkedBinaryTree(LinkedBinaryTree.Node(element, left[0], right[0]))

    a = create_expression_tree("* 2 + - 15 6 4", -1)
```

This approach does not work, as the nodes are not placed correctly. I would like to avoid using stacks, since I want a purely recursive implementation.

FYI: This is not a duplicate. I have reviewed others answers and I have tried implementing them but result in the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `prefix_exp_str[1:]` to both the recursive calls. Instead, the second recursive call needs to receive whatever is left of the input string after the first recursive call is finished.